# PyCharm - how to change the mouse colour

Tags: pycharm

I'm quite familiar with Visual Studio Code, but have just changed to PyCharm for work reasons. At the moment, when I move the mouse around on the screen, it is black, which is annoying because it blends in with the black background.

How do I change the colour of the mouse? I couldn't find it under file -> settings.

Comment: thanks, I will try to remember to do that.   Hopefully the orange arrow worked aw well !

Comment: No problem, yes the orange arrow worked you should be able to see the 1 in front of the comment. I honestly think you should take some time to go through your past questions, see which answers actually solved the questions, and accept those answers. You'll see folks will be much more likely to take your questions going forward.